# Generate histogram from JavaRDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to write code for converting data in Java RDD to a histogram so that I can bin the data in a certain way. For example, for the data I want to create a histogram of sizes such that I can find out which bin contains how many entries of a certain size range. I am able to get the value in different RDD's but I am not sure what I am missing here.

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
0 - 1 GB - 2 entries
1 - 5GB - 4 entries 
and so on
```

```
EntryWithSize {
 long size;
 String entryId;
 String groupId;
}


JavaRDD<EntryWithSize> entries = getEntries();

JavaRDD<HistoSize> histoSizeJavaRDD = entryJavaRDD.keyBy(EntryWithSize::getGroupId)
                .combineByKey(
                        HistoSize::new,
                        (HistoSize h, EntryWithSize y) -> h.mergeWith(new HistoSize(y)),
                        HistoSize::mergeWith
                ).values();

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class HistoSize implements Serializable {
        int oneGB;
        int fiveGB;
        public HistoSize(EntryWithSize entry) {
            addSize(entry);
        }

        private void addSize(EntryWithSize entry) {
            long size = entry.getSize();
            if (size <= ONE_GB) {
                oneGB++;
            } else {
                fiveGB++;
            }
        }

        public HistoSize mergeWith(HistoSize other) {
            oneGB += other.oneGB;
            fiveGB += other.fiveGB;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have got most of this working. I just need to merge the value with all the keys into one

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using a reduce on final pair rdd. My test data was wrong which was causing red herring in the output.

```
Function2<HistoSize, HistoSize, HistoSize> reduceSumFunc = (a, b) -> (new HistoSize(
            a.oneGB + b.oneGB,
            a.fiveGB + b.fiveGB,
    ));

HistoSize finalSize = histoSizeJavaRDD.reduce(reduceSumFunc);
```